# Wordpress multiple add_query_vars returns 404

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

Im using Wordpress 5.8, which is the latest version. Now im trying to make a pretty URL like https://example.com/jobs/1234/accountant.
Values in jobid and jobtitle are dynamic.

Here is my function;

```
add_action('init', function() {
    add_rewrite_rule( 'jobs/([a-z0-9-]+)[/]?$', 'index.php?pagename=jobs&jobid=$matches[1]&jobtitle=$matches[2]', 'top' );
} );

add_filter('query_vars', function($vars) {
    $vars[] = "jobid";
    $vars[] = "jobtitle";

    return $vars;
});
```

The above code only works for https://example.com/jobs/1234/

If I add another value next to jobid (1234) like (accountant) it returns to 404 page not found.

Is there a way to make it work? I dont want the url to be like https://example.com/jobs/1234/?jobtitle=accountant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up changing the regex and I don't get 404 now.

```
add_rewrite_rule( '^jobs/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php?pagename=jobs&jobid=$matches[1]&jobtitle=$matches[2]', 'top' );
```

To get the second value I extracted the url $wp->request().